# Purejavascript copy and past text form one text area to another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having to make a pure javascript form that will be completed on page and then printed straight of the page. 
I am having issues trying to figure out how to get it so the Address can be copied into the Postal address field.
Can't use Jquery or PHP, only pure javascript.

Here is a cut down version of what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>



<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>
  <label> Customers Address:
  </label>
      <textarea name=" Address" ID="custadd" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
</td>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>







delivery details below:
Name Address:<br/>
<textarea name="" ID="Deladd" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><p>
<button >Same as  address</button>





</body>

<script>



</script>

<style>

#myTable {

  border: none;;
font color:#000000
  font-size: 16px;
 border-collapse:collapse;
}

#myTable th{ 

font color:#000000

 font-size: 25px;

}



#myTable td {

font color:#000000
font color:#000000




}

#myTable tr {
background-color:#ff8080

}




</style>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to copy the contents of the first textarea into the second textarea when the user clicks the button.

First give your button an id, let's say `samebutton`. Then you can define an event handler for the click event:

```
document.getElementById("samebutton").onclick = function () {
  var custadd = document.getElementById("custadd").value;
  document.getElementById("Deladd").value = custadd
};
```

Here is a jsfiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/pcncuwp3/

Comment: You really should use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`.